# How to make Unity Singleton generic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently reviewing the Unity code.

and I'm studying about making Singleton generic.

Slowly I'm studying from Singleton.

I have a lot of question while reviewing the code.

That's it : `public class GameSingleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour`

1. What does it mean to specify MonoBehaviour as the constraint on the type parameter T?

And,

2. Why do usually use Singleton when creating a manager?

And,

3. When creating a Manager, `public class GameManager : GameSingleton<GameManager>{}`

I use these codes, what does that mean?

And,

4. How does the logic flow when these are implemented?

That is all..

What do I have to study to understand these things?

As a beginner, I do not know much. I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.`where T : MonoBehaviour`, means that any generic used by this class must inherit `MonoBehaviour` if it doesnt you will get a compile time error

2. Managers (in my experience) are usually singleton because of the high resource spin up time. For example, if you have a manager that is managing connections to your `redis` server, and are using stackexchanges redis nuget package. They state explicitly that you should have only One of their connections open, because it is thread safe and has a relatively expansive creation method.

3. `public class Gamemanager : GameSingleton<GameManager>.{}` this means you have a `GameManager` class that inherits `GameSingleton` with a `GameManager` as your generic.

4. To understand inheritence and Generics I would study [mcirosofts c# tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/)

5.To understand unity I would study [unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

Comment: Depends on what client you are using

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: What chat client do you want to chat with? google hangout, lync, gchat, old school aol chat. how would you like to chat? We can also do a conversation through stack

Comment: Oh!! I want stackoverflow chat.

Comment: ROOM NAME IS : Unity c#

Answer (score 0):

1) This means that the type `T` of the singleton you're going to create must inherit from `MonoBehaviour`, otherwise you'll get a compile error.

2) Because usually you don't want a specific manager to be present (i.e. number of instances) more than once in your scene. For example, think of a `ScriptManager` that handles all the `FixedUpdate`, `Update` and `LateUpdate` callbacks instead of letting Unity handle them: you don't want more than one such manager present in the scene. The Singleton pattern satisfies this condition (not more than one instance of `ScriptManager` in a scene).

3) It means that you're telling the compiler that type `T` is `GameManager`. If you look at the code of the class `GameSingleton<T>` you'll see that there's a `private static T _instance`, then a `public static T Instance` property, etc., and with this the `GameSingleton` class knows that `_instance` and `Instance` must be of type `GameManager`. Moreover, you can create different managers, by changing the type `T` (i.e.: GameManager, ScriptManager, CubesManager, whatever).

4) You need to study C# generics.

Comment: Case 1, If the format parameter's constraint is not MonoBehaviour, does it unconditionally fail during compilation? Is it just setting MonoBehaviour as a constraint to avoid errors? and Case 2, Case 3 Can you explain more easily?